# How to configure AtmelStudio 7 to add new lines at file end by default

Tags: visual-studio, newline, avr, atmel, atmelstudio

Atmel Studio does not add a new line at the end of a file by default.

**Background**

When developing AVR assembly, there is a [known issue](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_Known_Issues.html) with avrasm:

> AVRASM2 has some issues if the last line in a source file is missing a newline: Error messages may refer to wrong filename/line number if the error is in the last line of a included files, and in some cases syntax errors may result. Beware that the Atmel Studio editor will not append a missing newline at the end of a source file automatically.

Currently, i found [this](http://forums.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4700) feature request about adding an option to a plugin, which is delivered with AtmelStudio.

**Question**

How to configure Atmel Studio to add a new line by default?

**Update** *(2016-06-23)*

The following answer was sent from Atmel support regarding this issue:

> Currently there is no option to do this in Atmel Studio. We confirmed with internal team and we filed an improvement task to implement this in future.
>
> This option may be available in future version of Atmel Studio. But from our end we don’t know about the exact release date.

Comment: Since Atmel Studio is a Visual Studio shell, maybe you'll have more luck searching under Visual Studio for this?